# Trying to hash a password, but every time it just hashes to *0

Tags: php, database, security, encryption, blowfish

I'm learning how to hash passwords using PHP for obvious security reasons.  I have the two following functions for setting and checking hashes:

```
function password_encrypt($password)
{
    $hash_format = "$2y$10$"; //blowfish
    $salt_length = 22;
    $unique_random_string = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
    $base64_string = base64_encode($unique_random_string);
    $modified_base_64_string = str_replace('+', '.', $base64_string);
    $salt = substr($modified_base64_string, 0, $length);
    $format_and_salt = $hash_format . $salt;
    $hash = crypt($password, $format_and_salt);
    echo $hash;
    return $hash;
}

function password_check($password, $existing_hash)
{
    $hash = crypt($password, $existing_hash);
    if($hash === $existing_hash)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

My issue is that every time I hash a password and send it off to the database it just gets stored as *0.  I don't know where the *0 is coming from.  Is there something wrong with what I'm doing?

Basically when I use it I just grab the entered password from $_POST and encrypt it using password_encrypt().  But it seems like it always comes out the other side as *0.

Comment: Why are you doing this so hard? Why not just use hash() http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php

Comment: You should [use the proper methods to hash and verify passwords with PHP](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html).

Comment: At least you dont define `$length`

Comment: I'm following a tutorial on lynda.com....... this is exactly what he does haha

Comment: And $modified_base_64_string != $modified_base64_string

Comment: Change this line to make it works `    $salt = substr($modified_base_64_string, 0, $salt_length);`

Comment: @JayBlanchard when I use password_hash it creates the hash successfully but when I load that hash from the database and use password_verify to check it against the user-entered password, it is a mismatch every time.

Comment: Following the tutorial I sent you?

Comment: Yes.  As far as I can tell I'm following all the steps correctly.  For an example I set a password as "hashing" and hashed it, then stored it in my db.  It was stored as `$2y$10$NcMDiHqMdgWydDAU/JQUZeo` (copied and pasted) then I load this value when i want to verify it.  right before I use password_verify() I do this to double check that everything looks good `echo $hash . ":   " . $password;`  which prints out `$2y$10$NcMDiHqMdgWydDAU/JQUZeo: hashing` So everything is working fine until I get into `password_verify($password, $hash);` on the next line, which returns false every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Short and Correct Answer

Don't roll your own cryptography, use an implementation that has already been vetted by security experts. For PHP 5.5 and above, this means `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`. For earlier versions of PHP, you can use [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) (if your PHP version is older than 5.4, shame on you for running unsupported versions of PHP).

#### The [Crypto Self-Education](http://www.cryptofails.com/post/75204435608/write-crypto-code-dont-publish-it) Answer

If you're dead set on writing your own cryptography code (for the learning experience, etc.), you must promise to never deploy your unproven implementation and make anything depend on it for security. Otherwise, just use [`password_hash()`](https://secure.php.net/password_hash) and [`password_verify()`](https://secure.php.net/password_verify) and stop reading right now.

---

There are a lot of problems with your code. Let's go down the line systematically, starting with `password_encrypt()`. (By the way, you aren't encrypting a password, you're hashing it.)

```
$unique_random_string = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
```

Yeah, **NO**. This is not a cryptographically secure way to generate a salt for a bcrypt hash. You should take a look at how [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/402677b21b0e11fa4e6839dc92396a05bd702825/lib/password.php#L102-L139) implements this feature. Alternatively, see how [random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat) generates random bytes for cryptographic purposes. (Also, please tell whomever advised you to use that one-liner to generate random strings that they are playing with fire.)

```
$unique_random_string = random_bytes(17);
```

Moving on...

```
$modified_base_64_string = str_replace('+', '.', $base64_string);
$salt = substr($modified_base64_string, 0, $length);
```

You forgot an underscore in the second variable name. Also, there is no variable named `$length`. These lines, corrected, look like so:

```
$modified_base_64_string = str_replace('+', '.', $base64_string);
$salt = substr($modified_base_64_string, 0, $salt_length);
```

Next,

```
$hash = crypt($password, $format_and_salt);
echo $hash;
return $hash;
```

Please don't leave your echo statements in your example code. Also, you should check for errors and throw an exception so your application doesn't chug happily along if bcrypt hashing fails.

```
$hash = crypt($password, $format_and_salt);
if ($hash === '*0') {
    throw new Exception('Password hashing unsuccessful.');
}
return $hash;
```

Whew, almost done. Let's look at your `password_check()` function now:

```
if($hash === $existing_hash)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Don't compare cryptographic outputs (password hashes, MACs, etc.) using `==` or `===`, or else you invite [timing attacks](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2014/11/its-all-about-time.html) into your application. Use [`hash_equals()`](https://secure.php.net/hash_equals) for PHP 5.6, or [a `hash_equals()` polyfill for earlier versions of PHP](https://github.com/sarciszewski/php-future/blob/bd6c91fb924b2b35a3e4f4074a642868bd051baf/src/Security.php#L29-L50).

```
return hash_equals($hash, $existing_hash);
```

I hope this was an educational experience. Cryptography is hard, don't reinvent the wheel.